# Which point cloud library supports parsing from single 3d video stream?

Tags: opencv, openframeworks, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a static (with minor noize like moving grass) object (say statue/monument). I have a ardrone like quadrocopter that I controll. It sends to me single camera 720p stream. Can any PCL library turn that video stream into point cloud with correct depth?

Comment: look e.g. [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/02/07/structure-from-motion-and-3d-reconstruction-on-the-easy-in-opencv-2-3-w-code/) to estimate the amount of work needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to create a point cloud, you'll need a color image and a depth image (aka [depth map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_map)). The camera that you are using will need to be able to construct a depth image, which I believe is usually done with infrared light. The [Microsoft Kinect](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/) is an example of a camera that uses infrared to construct a depth image.

You can check out the ofxKinect example for more information. It gives an example of a point cloud generated from a kinect.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to get a Point Cloud from the Processing SimpleOpenNI library examples.

Following is the code I wrote for getting point-cloud from Kinect in processing:

```
//Code for Getting Point Cloud

import SimpleOpenNI.*;

import processing.opengl.*;

SimpleOpenNI kinect;

void setup()
{

  size( 1024, 768, OPENGL);

  kinect = new SimpleOpenNI( this );

  kinect.enableDepth();

}

void draw()
{

  background( 0);

  kinect.update();

  //translate( width/2,  height/2, -1000);

  rotateX( radians(180));

 stroke(255);

  PVector[] depthPoints = kinect.depthMapRealWorld();

  //the program get stucked in the for loop it loops 307200 times and I don't have any points output

  for( int i = 0; i < depthPoints.length ; i+=5)
  {

    PVector currentPoint = depthPoints[i];
  if (currentPoint.z < 2000.0)
    {
      point(currentPoint.x,  currentPoint.y, currentPoint.z );
    //print("currentPoint :", currentPoint );
    }
  }

}
```

You can get your Monument covered by the Kinect. But if you need the RGB output to be converted into Depth Data, that is not possible because Kinect throws infrared light on objects to calculate the depth, that is not possible through Streamed data. Even if you are using a Camera with Kinect, you can only use the RGB stream coming from it. For Depth, Using Kinect's sensor is your best bet. For better results use the new Kinect version 2.
Cheers!!